# How to compute the following Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to find the Fourier transform of

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases} e^{-ax}, & x \geq0\\ \ 0, & x < 0  \end{cases} $$

where $a>0$.

---

This is what I've done:

$$ F(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{iwx}dx =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax}e^{iwx}dx  $$ but I don't know what to use here to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z:=a-iw$ so$$|e^{-zx}|=e^{-ax}\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}|e^{-zx}|=0\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-zx}=0.$$So$$\int_0^\infty e^{-zx}dx=\left[\frac{-e^{-zx}}{z}\right]_0^\infty=\frac1z=\frac{a+iw}{a^2+w^2}.$$